# Build error of HybridPush SDK of bluemix

Tags: cordova, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ionic-framework, ibm-cloud

I am trying to use the hybrid SDK of Bluemix in an IONIC app, however I getting error in the first steps.

After to create an ionic app:

```
ionic start PushTeste tabs
ionic add platform ios
ionic plugin add com.ibm.mobile.cordova.ibmcloudcode 
ionic plugin add com.ibm.mobile.cordova.ibmpush
ionic build ios
```

I get the following error:

```
/Users/DaniloOliveira/tmp/PushIonic/platforms/ios/PushIonic/Plugins/com.ibm.mobile.cordova.ibmpush/CDVIBMPush.m:49:89: error: property 'token' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate *'
    NSString* token = [[[[((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).token description]
                                                                                        ^ 1 error generated.

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:    CompileC /Users/DaniloOliveira/PushIonic/platforms/ios/build/PushIonic.build/Debug-iphoneos/PushIonic.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDVIBMPush.o PushIonic/Plugins/com.ibm.mobile.cordova.ibmpush/CDVIBMPush.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (1 failure) Error: /Users/DaniloOliveira/tmp/PushIonic/platforms/ios/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 65
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

I am not native developer, neither Cordova plugins dev, so I don't know the structure of appe apps...

My env:

- XCode 6
- Mac 10.9.5
- Iphone 6 IOS 8.1.1

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, just follow the documentation. You need to make some adjustments in the SDK in order to make the SDK works.

http://mbaas-gettingstarted.ng.bluemix.net/hybrid#get-started-with-push

Comment: Can you comment about *what* adjustments need to be made? I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Ah. I was confused because it was a bit separated from the stuff on top. I got the error as soon as I added the plugin and never got to that part. So query, is it "Set up Push in Cordova for iOS" or "Set up IBM Push for Bluemix in Worklight for iOS"? I'm assuming #2?

Answer (score 0):

you had to reinstall one plugin and then for all other plugins, for which there were not

directories in the ios plugins directory for avoiding this error code.

More details are below:

http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-build-ios-plugin-errors-exit-code-65/7274